# What affects Alloy's scope?

Tags: alloy

The following model is ok, Alloy finds instances.

```
abstract sig A{}

sig B extends A{}
sig C extends A{}

run {} for 1 but exactly 1 B, exactly 1 C
```

That makes me understand that the scope is not limited by the top-level signature A, but by its extensions, B and C.

However, I have a large model (no sense posting it here) that can only be satisfied with the scope of 14. With a scope of 13 the analyzer finds no instances.

When I analyze the instance found, using the evaluator to request 'univ', I get a solution that has about 5 atoms of each signature. Only the top-level abstract signatures have 14 atoms.

Am I missing something about scope? Does it affect something else besides the signatures (such as predicates)? Does it behave differently than what I assumed with the toy example?

Why won't my model simulate with a scope of 5?

edit:
here is my model if anyone is interested in taking a look. It is the result of model transformation, that's why legibility is an issue http://pastebin.com/17Z00wV4

edit2:
the predicate below works. If I run the predicate for 5 but don't specify the other ranges explicitly, it doesn't find instances.

```
run story3 for 5 but exactly 4 World, exactly 4 kPerson, 
   exactly 0 kSoftwareTool, exactly 1 kSourceCode, 
   exactly 1 kDocument, exactly 1 kDiagram, exactly 3 kChange, 
   exactly 1 kProject, exactly 2 coBranch, exactly 1 coRepository, 
   exactly 3 modeConfiguration, exactly 2 modeAtomicVersion, 
   exactly 2 relatorChangeRequest, exactly 0 relatorVerification, 
   exactly 1 relatorCheckIn, exactly 1 relatorCheckOut, 
   exactly 2 relatorConfigurationSelection, 
   exactly 1 relatorModification, 
   exactly 0 relatorRequestEvaluation, exactly 2 relatorMarkup
```

this one does not (it's the same predicate, but without the "exactly" keywords

```
run story3 for 5 but exactly 4 World, 4 kPerson, 1 kSourceCode, 
   1 kDocument, 1 kDiagram, 3 kChange, 1 kProject, 2 coBranch, 
   1 coRepository, 3 modeConfiguration, 2 modeAtomicVersion, 
   2 relatorChangeRequest, 1 relatorCheckIn, 1 relatorCheckOut, 
   2 relatorConfigurationSelection, 1 relatorModification, 
   2 relatorMarkup
```

I was told Alloy would find any possible instances within the defined scope so

```
run story3 for 5
```

should work too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If each of the signature extending another one have a well defined scope, (it is the case for the small exemple you gave, then the the analyzer is "smart enough" to understand that the scope of the top level signature is at least equal to the some of the scopes of the signatures partitionning it.

In the case now you do not give any scopes to specific signatures, I assume that the analyzer won't be able to process the scope of the top signature as detailed bellow, the top level signature hence will have as scope the global one you gave.

Comment: thank you for your comment. Do you have knowledge of the internal workings of Alloy? Do you have anything I can read about that to better understand my problem?
I also added my model to the question if you want to take a look

Comment: Isn't my answer a solution to your problem ? I can find instances for the model you put on pastebin (by removing the open statements and the facts) so the scope is all right :-)

Comment: THE book that will introduce you to the Alloy way is "Software Abstractions" by Daniel Jackson. It will certainly answer most of your questions concerning Alloy.

Comment: I have read the book many years ago..
You answer is not a solution! I still cannot simulate the model with a scope of 5 :/ I want to know what makes the scope work differently than the toy example above.

Comment: Is this what you want then ?
run story3 for 5 World, 5 Property , 5 Object, 5 String_, 5 DataType 
No instances can be found for such scope given the set of constraints of your model

Comment: but if I try  "run story3 for 5 but exactly 4 World, exactly 4 kPerson, exactly 0 kSoftwareTool, exactly 1 kSourceCode, exactly 1 kDocument, exactly 1 kDiagram, exactly 3 kChange, exactly 1 kProject, exactly 2 coBranch, exactly 1 coRepository, exactly 3 modeConfiguration, exactly 2 modeAtomicVersion, exactly 2 relatorChangeRequest, exactly 0 relatorVerification, exactly 1 relatorCheckIn, exactly 1 relatorCheckOut, exactly 2 relatorConfigurationSelection, exactly 1 relatorModification, exactly 0 relatorRequestEvaluation, exactly 2 relatorMarkup" it works, so the scope of 5 is possible...

Comment: it seems the "exactly" keyword helps the analyzer to find the model instances, I've edited the question to add predicates that work and one that does not

Comment: I understand now the problem. Even if you set "run for 1 but 5 A", the Analyzer will expand the scope to 5, regardless of you defining the scope to 1.